# Conditional object to Map conversion

Tags: scala

I have a Scala case class, where some fields are `Option`. Like this:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[String] = None)
```

I would like to convert this object to a `Map[String, Any]`.

I have the following method:

```
def toMap: Map[String, Any] = {
   Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).collect {
     case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
}
```

However, this method returns empty Map.

### How should it be done?

//EDIT

Here's the example object of the Foo class:

```
val foo = Foo("bar")
val extFoo = Foo("ext", b = Some(12))
```

when calling `toMap` on this object, I want receive the following:

```
val fooMap = foo.toMap

println(fooMap)
// Map(a -> bar)

val extMap = extFoo.toMap

println(extMap)
// Map(a -> bar, b -> 12)
```

Basically, I want to remove key-value pairs, if the `Option` is equal to `None`, but still be able to map required fields.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling it? Looks fine to me. But keep in mind that you'll be losing `a` since it won't match `Some(value)`

Comment: Also, `Map[String, Any]` will probably cause you more problems than it solves. Not sure why you'd need such a heterogenous map... but you do you :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is the problem - I'm losing `a`. How can extend the cases, so they will match non-Option fields?

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to re-invent some kind of serialization mechanism, why not use a library?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm quite new to Scala, can you recommend any?

Comment: @Forin to waht format are you serializing? **Json**? Also, are you already using some ecosystem like **typelevel**, **ZIO**, **Akka**, **LiHaoyi**, etc?

Comment: This case class is part of larger structure, the structure itself is serialize to json using json4s. However, to build the main object I need pass my case class object in form of `Map[String, Any]`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: TL;DR**

to solve the issue you have, you would need to add another `case` to the [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) you are applying in the `collect` method where you catch the rest of the cases.

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[String] = None) {
  def toMapCollect: Map[String, Any] =
    Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).collect {
      case (key, value) if !value.isInstanceOf[None.type]  => key -> value
    }

  def toMapFilter: Map[String, Any] =
    Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).filter { keyValue =>
      val (_, value) = keyValue
      !value.isInstanceOf[None.type]
    }

  def toMapFilterNot: Map[String, Any] =
    Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).filterNot { keyValue =>
      val (_, value) = keyValue
      value.isInstanceOf[None.type]
    }

  // one more option is to build the Map manually, put the `Option`s in a `List[(String,Option[_])]` and check if they are not `None`
  def anotherToMap: Map[String,Any] = {
    Map("a" -> a) ++ List(("b" -> b), ("c" -> c)).filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
  }
}
```

The `collect` method is similar to apply a filter and then a `map`.

Not sure exactly what you are trying to solve, but this doesn't look like a good approach. Using [Any](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) could force you to make type casting later.

---

Based on the provided code, the only case where `toMap` returns an **empty Map**, is when `b` and `c` fields are `None`. If I wrote the following

```
val foo1 = Foo("1", None, None)
val foo2 = Foo("2", Some(2), None)
val foo3 = Foo("3", None, Some("3"))
val foo4 = Foo("4", Some(4), Some("4"))

println(s"foo1: ${foo1.toMap}")
println(s"foo2: ${foo2.toMap}")
println(s"foo3: ${foo3.toMap}")
println(s"foo4: ${foo4.toMap}")
```

the output will be

```scala
foo1: Map()
foo2: Map(b -> 2)
foo3: Map(c -> 3)
foo4: Map(b -> 4, c -> 4)
```

we can observe the following:

- `a` is always discarded
- `b` and `c` are only kept when they are `Some`

---

If we check the documentation of [Map.collect](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#collect%5BK2,V2%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5B(K,V),(K2,V2)%5D):CC%5BK2,V2%5D), we can see that the scaladoc and the signature of that function is the following

```scala
  /** Builds a new collection by applying a partial function to all elements of this `map`
    *  on which the function is defined.
    *
    *  @param pf     the partial function which filters and maps the `map`.
    *  @tparam K2    the key type of the returned `map`.
    *  @tparam V2    the value type of the returned `map`.
    *  @return       a new `map` resulting from applying the given partial function
    *                `pf` to each element on which it is defined and collecting the results.
    *                The order of the elements is preserved.
    */
  def collect[K2, V2](pf: PartialFunction[(K, V), (K2, V2)]): Map[K2, V2]
```

This means that `collect` receives a parameter named `pf` of type [PartialFunction](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/PartialFunction.html). A **function** has a domain where is defined, a **partial function** is also a **function** but the domain is a **subdomain** (it could the complete domain, just a subset or it could be empty).

---

If we consider the function `square root`, the domain (only real numbers) is 0 and positive numbers. In scala, you can define a `PartialFunction` for square root like this

```scala
val squareRoot: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = {
  case x if x >= 0 => Math.sqrt(x)
}
```

The trait `PartialFunction` provides the function `isDefinedAt` that lets you know if the function is defined at an specific value.

---

What you are doing for each `case x if condition => value` you are applying something named [Pattern Matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). When you write

```scala
case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
```

you are saying that you will only consider any `String` for the `key` and only `Some[Any]` for the `value` of the Map.

---

Backing to the function you defined

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[String] = None) {
  def toMap: Map[String, Any] =
    Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).collect {
      case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
    }
}
```

we could write the same code like this

```scala
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Int] = None, c: Option[String] = None) {
  val partialFunction: PartialFunction[(String,Any),(String,Any)] = {
    case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
  }
  def toMap: Map[String, Any] =
    Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b, "c" -> c).collect(partialFunction)
}
```

Then we could ask to the `partialFunction` if it is defined at different values.

```scala
// based that the PartialFunction is typed as [(String,Any),(String,Any)],
// we can only pass a tuple of type (String, Any) to `isDefinedAt`

// these will return true
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("someInt",Some(1234)))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("someString",Some("some string")))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("someBoolean",Some(false)))

// these will return false
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("none",None))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("string","string"))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("boolean",true))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("int",5))
partialFunction.isDefinedAt(("double",1.5))
```

Comment: Using your solution still returns empty Map. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Such us how the case class is defined with the function, the piece of code that is returning the empty map? Edit your post and add as much information as you can.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example usage.

Comment: based on the **edit** you did, you will get an empty Map for `foo` and a Map with just the key `b` for `fooExt`. If you want to also keep the `a` field, you need to add a case (below the one you have because the checks occurs in sequential order based on how they where written)  where you catch the rest of the types. Something like `case (key, value) -> key -> value`. The `collect` is similar to apply `filter` and then `map`

Comment: I tried to add the `case(key, value) => key -> value` however, then I'm getting also `None` values. Is there a way to make sure I will get only required fields and those with Some?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote the code quickly and didn't check it. So. to discard all the `None`s you could check the type of the instance with `value.isInstanceOf[None.type]`. Based that you only want to discard values and not apply any transformation, maybe with `filter` or `filterNot` could be enough. I will edit that part of the code. This is not something exactly good. You are checking types in runtime. Scala has a really powerful type system that let you avoid this kind of things in most of the cases. Not sure what is the whole context in your case to do some refactor